# how to dynamically enable and disable button when checkbox is checked and unchecked in semantic UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, semantic-ui

How does one dynamically enable and disable the button when the checkbox is checked and unchecked in semantic UI, I've spent so much time to do this.

Here is the html

```
<div class="ui fitted checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" > <label></label>
</div>
<div class="ui small positive disabled button" id="edit">
<i class="edit icon"></i> Edit
</div>
```

Here is my javascript

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
                    if (
                    $('#cek').checkbox({
                        onChecked: function () {
                        }
                    })) {
                        $('#edit').removeClass('disabled');
                    } else {
                        $('#edit').addClass('disabled');       
                    }
                });
</script>
```

Please help, it drives me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) like

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
             $('[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
                     $('#edit').toggleClass('disabled');
                 });
             });
```

This will add the class if it does not exist or remove it if it does.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
         
          $('#edit').toggleClass('disabled');
        });
      });
```

```css
.disabled {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui fitted checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <label></label>
</div>
<div class="ui small positive disabled button" id="edit">
  <i class="edit icon"></i> Edit
</div>
```

Comment: @AudioAlief, sorry there was a syntax error. See it now

Comment: @AmmarCE, i appriciate your code man,but in semantic, to make the checkbox is checked you must add the js something like : 


`$('ui.checkbox').checkbox();` , so if i use your code,i must remove the 

`<div class=ui fitted button></div>` , and  left the checkbox unstyled

Comment: @AudioAlief, thats fine, include `$('ui.checkbox').checkbox();` before my code and it should work

Comment: `$('ui.checkbox').checkbox();


$(document).ready(function() {
             $('[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
                     $('#edit').toggleClass('disabled');
                 });
             });`

thats all didnt work, i swear :(

Comment: no need to apologize , i appriciate your answer man,it was helpful,really ,thank you so much brother :D

Comment: @AudioAlief, please unaccept my answer. i want to remove it and SO wont let me because it is accepted. I dont believe this should be an accepted answer if it didnt help you with your semantic-ui problem

Comment: the function is worked,but i must remove the style `<div class=ui fitted button></div>` , but thats fine,no problem